# I need help solving a logarithm equation.

Tags: logarithms

these were my steps.
Can someone tell me where have i goe wrong since the answer is
 $-{\frac 14}$.

$\sqrt{\log(\sqrt{10}a)} = {\frac 12}$

${\frac 12}{\log(\sqrt{10}a)} = \log\sqrt{10}$

${\log(\sqrt{10}a)}^{\frac 12} = {\log\sqrt10}$ because $(\log_ax^n = n\log_ax)$

$(\sqrt{10}a)^{\frac 12} = 10^{\frac 12}$ (squaring)

$10^{\frac 12}a = 10$ division by $10^{\frac 12}$

$ a = 10^{1-\frac 12}$

$a = \sqrt{10}$

Comment: how did you obtain the second line equation??

Comment: what appears to me is that you made a silly mistake in line 2.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{\log(\sqrt{10}a)}=\frac12$

$\log(\sqrt{10}a)=\frac14$

$\sqrt{10}a=10^{1/4}$

$a=10^{-1/4}$

Answer (score 0):

The first step you take is incorrect.

\begin{align}
\sqrt{\log(\sqrt{10}a)} & = {\frac 12} \\
\log(\sqrt{10}a) & = \frac{1}{4} \\
\log(\sqrt{10}a) & = \log(10^{\frac 14}) \\
\sqrt{10}a = 10^{\frac 14} \\
a = 10^{-\frac 14}
\end{align}